# In Android, image sizing while supporting multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, xml

In my android app, I want to support multiple screen sizes. I realize that for Android "large" means a lot of the current phone screens at 480 x 800 pixels as well as a 7" tablet like the Nexus 7 which has 800 x 1280 pixels. But I'd like to create 2 separate layouts for those two display sizes. I've found that rather than using `res/layout-large`, using `res/layout-h800dp` gives me greater control of which size screen uses what layout. (I'm using a portrait orientation, hence h800dp) The problem I'm having is this: sometimes the h800dp layout uses the images in the drawable-mdpi folder, and sometimes it uses the images in the drawable-hdpi folder. I'm using the same syntax in the xml to call the images: `android:src="@drawable/image", but in one activity it looks in the mdpi drawable folder, and in the next activity, it looks in the ldpi drawable folder. Is there any way to get the h800dp layouts to always look in the ldpi folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) explains nearly everything regarding screen properties (DPI, physical size, resolution, etc.)

What you may be able to do is specify folders like layout-large-hdpi, layout-large-mdpi, and layout-large-ldpi.

Experiment with blending these types together in folder names.

Comment: I've read that page, that's where I learned about the h800dp idea. But I'll give your suggestion on folder names a shot.

Comment: I'm still messing with it, but it appears that naming my layout folders "layout-large-hdpi" and "layout-mdpi" appears to work.